# MDI Child Graphics

Tags: vb.net

I have a home-form where the MDIContainer is enabled in it and I set it to be the parent form while I have other child forms to be opened inside, the child forms are set to be opened maximized programmatically. here is the code:

```
With childform1
        .MdiParent = Me
        For Each frm As Form In Me.MdiChildren
            If frm.Name <> .Name Then frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
        Next
        .StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
        .WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
        .Show()
End With
```

the issue is; because the child forms have a lot of controls and underneath processes it takes so much to be maximized, and the GUI shows the process of maximizing the MDI child form ( start by the normal screen and sizing it to the maximized form)

I believe there is a way that shows only the maximized form without the process of maximizing the forms ?
* doubleBuffered is set to True

Comment: Start by setting the `DoubleBuffered` property to `True` and hopefully you'll see improvement.

Comment: I did try it already, however, the same thing happens, i guess i need to postpone the loading or showing up the form until it has been already maximized

Comment: I have no idea what an "underneath process" is, but it is not just about drawing controls - all the code in the FormLoad needs to run as well - if you are doing a lot there, that can be the real problem

Comment: the underneath processes are reading different data-tables from SQL database, normally this process won't affect how fast the application is. when I tried to open the form as just by .showdialog() it worked faster than MDI child.